# Как заставить проигрывать аудио в ie7-8 с помощью flash?

Tags: internet-explorer, аудио, flash-player, javascript

Господа, возникла проблема с mediaelement js. Аудио (mp3) воспроизводится везде без проблем, кроме и ie7-8. Пытаюсь разобраться, как заставить воспроизводить через flashmediaelement.swf

В документации на сайте http://mediaelementjs.com/ примеров не нашел.